# Баг счётчика ежедневного посещения сайта

Tags: дефект

Посещаю форум ежедневно и отслеживая счётчик ежедневного посещения сайта в разделе "знаки", заметил, что счётчик обнуляется, если я посещаю сайт в течение дня только из яндекс браузера на мобильном устройстве, то есть если я не захожу на сайт с моего пк.

Устройство: Samsung Galaxy A30s

ОС: Android 10

Браузер: Яндекс.Браузер - с Алисой, версия 21.6.1.128

Comment: Так может просто на мобильном устройстве не авторизованы?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ обижаете) конечно же авторизован

Comment: Тогда это странно, т.к. посещения фиксируются в любом случае на серверной стороне. Ещё могу предположить, что открылась страница из кеша и реального обращения к сайту действительно не было. Плюс надо иметь в виду учёт времени по UTC.

Comment: Условие со временем по UTC - соблюдено. Кэширование, если оно и имело место быть всё равно основывается на ответе сервера, а значит  - это баг, так как я посещаю сайт ежедневно и в какой то момент счётчик обнуляется, даже если это из за кеширования. Я бы уже давно получил знак "Фанатик" если бы не это баг. Я попытаюсь разобраться с этим и протестирую другие браузеры на досуге.

Comment: Недостаточно просто посетить сайт. Нужно проявить активность: написать вопрос или ответ, оставить комментарий.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov где вы это прочитали? Во первых таких условий нет в разделе "знаки" для знака "Фанатик", а во вторых счётчик работает правильно, если я посещаю сайт с моего пк и при этом я не  проявляю активность: не пишу вопрос или ответ, не оставляю комментарий

Comment: Личный опыт. Я замечал такое же поведение при заходе с ПК. Пусть даже не писать ничего, но нужно хотя бы открыть какую-нибудь тему. Захода на главную страницу сайта недостаточно.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov возможно - нужно проверить, но согласитесь, что это баг, так как фактический результат не соответствует ожидаемому)) Да ещё и трудно воспроизводимый, если допустить, что счётчик только иногда обнуляется если зайти на сайт и не проявить активность, ведь мной установлено, что чаще счётчик отрабатывает корректно если зайти на сайт с пк не проявить активность

Comment: На Мете у меня нет знака Фанатик. Хотя за все эти годы я гарантированно посещал его сто дней подряд неоднократно. Просто я открываю главную страницу, смотрю названия тем, если ничего интересного - закрываю. Итог: посещение не засчитано. А вот если в темы позаглядываю - считается.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov В разделе "знаки" для знака "Фанатик" определено: "Посещать сайт ежедневно в течение 100 дней подряд (учёт дней по UTC)" если просто посещать недостаточно, то нужно изменить условие: "Посещать сайт ежедневно в течение 100 дней подряд и проявлять любую активность: написать вопрос или ответ, оставить комментарий (учёт дней по UTC)"

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov раньше, кстати, был календарь посещений, а теперь его [упразднили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368371/339911). Вообще, я тоже как-то не предполагал, что нужно в вопросы заходить, хорошо бы это уточнить официально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [ответу на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266227/339911) факт "посещения" сайта учитывается при совершении несколько более комплексных действий, нежели просто открытие/перезагрузка главной страницы сайта. Конкретные действия не афишируются, но логично предположить, что действия, которые оставляют "след", видимый другим посетителям на сайте должны считаться как посещение. Например, публикация сообщений, комментариев, голосование и т.д.

При этом однозначно [заявлено](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485/339911), что простого входа на сайт недостаточно для того, чтобы считать это посещением.

Comment: Завтра проверю, сработает ли счётчик, если просто зайду на сайт, не оставив "след".

Comment: Хм, я вроде проявляю активность не всегда, а «1713 дней подряд» продолжает капать. Наверное, простой просмотр вопросов тоже засчитывается

Comment: @andreymal вполне допускаю. Всё же изучение текста сообщений - это индикатор проявления чуть большего интереса, чем просто просмотр заголовков.

Comment: Всё верно - открытие/перезагрузка главной страницы не увеличивает счётчик посещения. Проверил. Благодарю за ответ!